# Why eggs, onions, and garlic?

Tags: eggs, maseches-niddah, ruach-rah

The Gemara in [Niddah (17a)](https://www.sefaria.org/Niddah.17a.4?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes:

> אמר ר"ש בן יוחי ה' דברים הן שהעושה אותן מתחייב  בנפשו ודמו בראשו
> האוכל שום קלוף  ובצל קלוף וביצה קלופה והשותה משקין מזוגין שעבר עליהן
> הלילה והלן בבית הקברות...Rabbi Shimon ben Yochai further says: There
> are five actions with regard to which one who performs them is held
> liable for his own life, and his blood is upon his own head, i.e., he
> bears responsibility for his own demise. They are as follows: One who
> eats peeled garlic or a peeled onion or a peeled egg, and one who
> drinks diluted drinks; all these are referring to items only when they
> were left overnight...

Without getting into the questions whether this issue applies nowadays, many commentators [see [Ben Yehoyada Nidda 17a](https://www.sefaria.org/Niddah.17a.4?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&p2=Ben_Yehoyada_on_Niddah.17a.3&lang2=bi), [Shevet Halevi (3:169)](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1413&pgnum=204), and [Divrei Yatziv YD (1:31)]](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15081&st=&pgnum=80&hilite=) explains the concern is based on ruach ra'ah. What is special about garlic, onions, and eggs that they are particularly sensitive to being affected by ruach ra'ah more than any other food?

Comment: I've read somewhere that garlic and onion were considered the food of the Egyptians. Might not be much but it's a lead to answer your question (hopefully)

Comment: https://food.ndtv.com/food-drinks/why-you-shouldnt-store-peeled-onions-1822905#:~:text=possibly%20go%20wrong%3F-,It%20is%20believed%20that%20peeled%20onions%20shouldn't%20be%20stored,a%20host%20of%20health%20problems. According to Health Practitioner and Macrobiotic Health Coach Shilpa Arora, "Bacteria contaminate onions once exposed and if they are left as it is, they may get oxidized further leading to a host of health problems.